# What's the best practice to securely authenticate in rails using Facebook from iOS?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

I want to use devise/omniauth. I see there is a facebook gem and also a facebook-access-token gem, both of which are giving me different issues. What is the best practice at this point for authenticating in RoR from iOS using oauth2? For now, just FB, but soon other as well.

I would like to be as secure as possible. My preference was to get a signed request out of the iOS SDK and pass that to RoR but it looks like that is not possible (perhaps because I don't have the secret on the mobile app [and I don't want to put it there]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your are using [omniauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) the best practice is using a specific  omniauth strategy gem for every auth provider you want to support and in case of facebook, this will be [omniauth-facebook](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/omniauth-facebook)

Update 1:
Considerung you comment, in that case you don't need omniauth at all. Just open the facebook oauth login within a webview setting the redirect_url to a [custom url schema](http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified) (Section: Android or Others). After the redirect parse the token out of the webview location and send it to the server. The [most used facebook clients](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/api_clients) are koala and fb_graph.

It's by the way not "as secure as possible", because you could omit exposing the facebook auth token to the client at all, however the risk of stealing the token on malicious phone is very limited and at the end it is not some bank api you are dealing with. And these days a lot of apps do client access to facebook and other social networks

Comment: But I do not want to do the server-side oauth flow, I want to do a client flow on my iOS device. After the user has authenticated locally on their device, I want to send the access_token to the RoR server so that I can continue to use it on the server.

Comment: I ended up using omniauth-facebook-access-token to handle this. I didn't want to roll my own.